# How to connect TBS Crossfire nano rx to Matek F405-WMN?

Tags: flight-controller, receiver, crossfire-nano

How to connect crossfire nano rx to FC Matek F405-WMN? I don't see commands receiver connection on the wiring diagram http://www.mateksys.com/?portfolio=f405-wmn#tab-id-4

Is it possible to connect two receivers (2.4GHz and 868/915MHz) to one FC and switch them on-fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the section of the layout diagram with the four white boxes, in the bottom right. The white boxes represent common receiver types. The top white box labelled CRSF is for Crossfire receivers.

[image: Receiver wiring]

The section of the flight controller marked by a yellow line indicates the pads used by receivers.

The reason for this is that some receivers don't include telemetry, so don't use the TX2 pad, and SBUS receivers send an inverted signal that needs to be handled slightly differently.

No, you can't connect multiple receivers. Instead many receivers have two antennas and automatically use the one with the best signal.

Comment: Wow! I thought, that it is different devices, not receivers. Thank you

Comment: What if we use radio receiver for planes without FC like this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2007715862.html which has few PWM channels. Is it possible to connect this kind of receivers to the FC? Do we need some additional device?

Comment: I don't think you could use that receiver. Many older flight controllers (Naze32, CC3D) did have connections for individual PWM channels, but 6+ pads takes up a lot of space (plus 2 for power), so most FCs now just use a protocol that puts all channels on one wire. That receiver has a PPM pin, which is a single wire protocol, but there's a note on the FC diagram saying that iNAV4 doesn't support PPM. I think that you could just wire it up like a CRSF receiver if you were using BetaFlight (and tell Betaflight that it's PPM), but that doesn't have the GPS functions you probably need.